# "Undefined symbol" linker error even if symbol is defined in other library

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++, static-libraries

I am facing a strange kind of linker error during linking of static library , following is my problem:

I am creating one application say "myapplication" as blow:

```
g++ myapplication.o  -L /dirctory_with_liba.a -L /dirctory_with_libb.a -la -lb  -o myapplication
```

its giving following output:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
print_msg_cpp                ./liba.a(d.o)
```

now suppose liba.a consist of following object files:

```
c.o
d.o
e.o
```

and libb.a consist of following object files:

```
f.o
g.o
h.o
```

and symbol print_msg_cpp is defined in g.o which is a part of libray libb.a.

Now I am just not able to understand that why its giving undefine symbol error , even after including -lb. Any suggestions?

Following is output of nm command:

```
nm liba.a | grep print_msg_cpp
[240]   |         0|         0|NOTY |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |print_msg_cpp


nm libb.a | grep print_msg_cpp
[11]    |       180|        36|FUNC |LOCL |0    |1      |_GLOBAL__D__Z20print_msg_cppitPciP2container_headerRSt19basic
[9]     |       216|        36|FUNC |LOCL |0    |1      |_GLOBAL__I__Z20print_msg_cppitPciP2container_headerRSt19basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEiz
[33]    |       252|      1416|FUNC |GLOB |0    |1      |_Z20print_msg_cppitPciP20Bcontainer_headerRSt19basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEiz
```

Comment: Hard to tell since this is not real code and you have omitted unknown amount of details, any of which could be vital. Does your real link line list -la and -lb in the same order you have in the question?

Comment: yes...i have checked g++ -v option...linker is taking in same order...

Comment: Say `nm libb.a | grep print_msg_cpp` what do you see?

Comment: I don't believe that `print_msg_cpp` is defined in your library. The best thing to be certain about this is to check that with nm command as n.m said. I would suggest to use `c++filt` comand so that output will be more readable :)
`nm libb.a | grep print_msg_cpp | c++filt`

Comment: updated the Q with ouptput of nm command..

Comment: Why is the symbol in `liba.a` not mangled and why are the symbols in `libb.a` are mangled?  Is `liba.a` written in C?  If so, you need to provide the function it is to call with an `extern "C"` declaration in the C++ code so that it can be called from C.

Comment: both are cpp code....I really dont understand why one is mangled and other is not , but same linking is woking in g++ version 2.8.1 , and I am using g++ 4.1.2 in which linker is giving error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It seems related to name mangling only , I just took a other sample c++ file , and compiled it using g++ 2.8.1 and make it part of a library. Now when I see symbol table of library using nm command , I found that name is not mangled at all. When I repeat same procedure using  g++ 4.1.2  , name is mangled.

Comment: If both files are C++ source code, that strongly suggests there are some `extern "C"` declarations around.  You'll need to track them down and work out what you need to do to make the code self-consistent across the various files.  Either the `extern "C"` needs to be dropped so the names are mangled, or the `extern "C"` needs to be propagated to where the C-callable function is defined.